# Switching current website to new Rails app - SEO redirecting best practices

Tags: redirect, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, seo

I have just created a new rails web app for my business, but want to keep the old domain name for google SEO purposes.  How do I go about redirecting the old links to the new links on the same domain?

For instance, I have this old page ...
http://www.horschgallery.com/photo/black-white-chicago-vertical/chicago-cityscape-photo-sears-tower-willis-tower.aspx

that will need to be redirected to the new page which is currently hosted on heroku
http://horschgallery.herokuapp.com/photos/chicago-cityscape-photo-sears-tower-willis-tower

but I'll want to put the heroku app on the horschgallery.com domain (which doesnt exist yet as I need to change the IP address that my server points to)
horschgallery.com/photos/chicago-cityscape-photo-sears-tower-willis-tower

Answer (score 0):

paste this code in your old domain and put domain url

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "http://example.com";
}
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">

</body>
```

or click here --> [Changing Your URL Without Penalizing Your Search Engine Optimization](http://webdesign.about.com/od/http/a/aa021207.htm)